# How to pass a dataframe column to scala function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've written a scala function which will convert time(HH:mm:ss.SSS) to seconds. First it will ignore milliseconds and will take only (HH:mm:ss) and convert into seconds(int). It works fine when testing in spark-shell.

```
def hoursToSeconds(a: Any): Int = {
 val sec = a.toString.split('.')
 val fields = sec(0).split(':')
 val creationSeconds = fields(0).toInt*3600 + fields(1).toInt*60 + fields(2).toInt
 return creationSeconds
}

print(hoursToSeconds("03:51:21.2550000"))
13881
```

I would need to pass this function to one of the dataframe column(running), which i was trying with the withColumn method, but getting error **Type mismatch, expected: column, actual String**. Any help would be appreciated, is there a way i can pass the scala function to udf and then use udf in df.withColumn.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- vin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BeginOfDay: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Timezone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Running: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Idling: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Stopped: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dlLoadDate: string (nullable = false)
```

sample **running** column values.

[image]

```
df.withColumn("running", hoursToSeconds(df("Running")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a udf for the `hoursToSeconds` function by using the following sytax :

```
val hoursToSecUdf = udf(hoursToSeconds _)
```

Further to use it on a particular column the following sytax can be used :

```
df.withColumn("TimeInSeconds",hoursToSecUdf(col("running")))
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename